# Invalid currency code -error getting on checkout page in woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I made an e commerce website using woo-commerce. Everything was working fine but i got an error while punching the order on checkout page. The error is  " Invalid currency code " I am adding a screenshot of the error as well and one more thing some code appears in url after domain when i open the website.
The website is https://www.janvifashionflower.com/.  Whenever i open the website domain automatically redirects to https://www.janvifashionflower.com/?v=c86ee0d9d7ed , kindly help me with both issues.

This is screenshot of Invalid Currency Code error:

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kuik8d

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If yes, let me know how

Answer (score 0):

Custom currencies can be added through your theme's functions.php file. [More Info](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-custom-currency-symbol/)

Alternatively, you can install the [plugin for your currency](https://wordpress.org/plugins/indian-rupee-symbol-for-woocommerce/).